# How I write this code without functions

Tags: python, arrays, function

This is real code that I want to write that code without function.

```
import sys
    from fractions import gcd

    n = int(sys.argv[1])

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            GCD = gcd(i, j)
            if GCD == 1:
                sys.stdout.write("* ")
            else:
                sys.stdout.write(" ")
        print
```

that code's output is;
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQyrL.jpg)
and my code that I tried. But it doesn't work like above code.

```
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])

for x in range(n):
    for y in range(n):
        while y != 0:
            temp = y
            y = x % y
            x = temp
        GCD = x

        if GCD == 1:
            sys.stdout.write("* ")
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(" ")
    print
```

and my code's output is;
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEhy3.jpg)
How i do it like first code's ouput without functions.

edit: I don't know actually is sys.stdout.write built in fuction.
so I will explain. It is like print function without new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import sys

n = int(sys.argv[1])

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
         a,b =i,j
         while b:
             a, b = b, a%b
        GCD = a
        if GCD == 1:
            sys.stdout.write("* ")
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(" ")
    print
```

Comment: If you try this code, you can see this code doesn't work. I tried this code too. Output is same my code.

Comment: I am sooooo thank you. At least last 3 days I tried to solve this question. But you did it. thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah It's right. but I am wondering one thing. Sorry If I am not learning that I am wondering things, I can't improving.

why when I change a and b with i and j, it doesn't work?
I mean,

while j:
and i,j = j, i%j
ı hope you understand

Comment: @njx that's a good question, maybe post it as a new question, with both blocks of code (working and stopped-working)

Comment: I understand a little bit. It is about reset. thank you for posting.